# Filtering in Queries using Linked Servers in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, linked-server

My colleague told me that any query that uses a linked server first transfers the data from the remote server to the server the query is running on and then applies filters. For example, if I have the following query:

```
select id, region
from linked_server.mydb.dbo.product
where id = 1
```

The query will bring all the data from the remote server's product table to the local server and apply `ID=1`. I couldn't find this information on the Microsoft website. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any query that uses a linked server first transfers the data from the remote server to the server the query is running on and then applies filters...Is this true?

It depends, but yes it can happen. There are two primary operations within an execution plan for a query that accesses a Linked Server: `Remote Scan` and `Remote Query`.

Depending on what information the optimizer has available to it, what indexes are on the tables involved on the remote side, and the query itself, a `Remote Scan` operation may get chosen which will scan the entire table on the remote side, and return all of the data from it across the Linked Server, before filtering it down on the local side.

With proper indexing, and a well written query, it is possible to influence the optimizer to use the *generally* more efficient operation of a `Remote Query`, which will execute the filters on the remote side, before returning the data across the Linked Server.

I've personally found that you can generally influence the optimizer to use the more efficient `Remote Query` operation when the data is properly indexed on the remote side, and the query in question filters by those indexed fields, or minimally by the primary key of the table.

You may find more helpful information on the subject in [Efficiently polling remote data sources](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/performance-sql-server/efficiently-polling-remote-data-sources/).